# Group values in a flat array by leading integer to form a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

What the simple way to convert this single array :

```
$array = [
    '1.1',
    '1.2',
    '1.3',
    '2.1',
    '2.2',
    '2.3',
    '3.1',
    '3.2',
];
```

into a multidimensional array like this one:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1.1
        [2] => 1.2
        [3] => 1.3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2.1
        [2] => 2.2
        [3] => 2.3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 3.1
        [2] => 3.2
    )
)
```

The number of rows and columns can change (input by user), and inside of the cell is the same as the combination of both (like shown).

Comment: You would iterate over each entry and add them to the relevant key in the end array. Have you tried to foreach over it?

Comment: a better question is why does everyone use `print_r` instead of `var_export`, frustrating.

Comment: `$key = substr( $item, 0,1);` to get the keys you need ( inside a foreach ), then build a new array.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix hah! indeed ;) but then.. you actually bother trying to write the loop?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - I already have an answer, with `array_walk` foreach is to much typing for me.

Comment: array_chunk is a native php function.

Comment: Can it exceed `9.x` as in `10.x`

Comment: You'll need to describe what you need a little better. Do you simply want to sort values by what comes before the decimal place? What are the actual inputs and then the actual output you expect? Do you want the array key defined by the value on the left of the decimal? If the answers below don't solve your need then you haven't ask what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
<?php
$origArray = array(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2);
$chunkedArray = array_chunk($origArray, 3);
foreach($chunkedArray as $increment => $chunk){
  $resultArray[$increment+1] = $chunk;
}
print_r($resultArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer you're looking for is called array_chunk().

```
<?php
$input_array = Array(
[0] => 1.1
[1] => 1.2
[2] => 1.3
[3] => 2.1
[4] => 2.2
[5] => 2.3
[6] => 3.1
[7] => 3.2
)
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 3));

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1.1
        [2] => 1.2
        [3] => 1.3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2.1
        [2] => 2.2
        [3] => 2.3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 3.1
        [2] => 3.2
    )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: What if the 4th item is `5.6`.  What happens then? see `The number of rows and columns can change `

Comment: I don't see anywhere that it needs to be ordered. The 3 is the number of columns per row. He could replace that with the user input number of columns if he wanted.

Comment: please see this, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5ddd3de0e8de1ce87c3c007eff524bd7ca0c3f9  where it breaks down if the number of rows change, as stated in the question.

Comment: Your solution is very good. In my case if there were more numbers or the the number of chunks changed then the number of rows and columns would change. Aside from the initial question he hasn't elaborated any further. I think you read too much into how he phrased it.

Comment: Alas, I am the type of person forced to examine all the edge cases... I blame it on my years of toil behind the neon glow of the computer screen .... lol

Comment: i need that to be in order... its a mesh of infinity elements , each element have the right place to stay

Answer (score 0):

I would use array walk, just because I'm to lazy to type out `foreach( ..bla.. ..bla.. )`

```
$array = Array(
    '1.1',
    '1.2',
    '1.3',
    '2.1',
    '2.2',
    '2.3',
    '3.1',
    '3.2',
);

$res = [];

array_walk( $array, function($item) use (&$res){
    $key = substr($item, 0,1); //get the first place, this will work up to # 9
    if( isset($res[$key]))
        $res[$key][] = $item;
    else
        $res[$key] = [$item];
});

var_export( $res );
```

You can test it here, even.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0988bc488a732270589106c0ea7738f36e4a9407

Outputs

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1.1',
    1 => '1.2',
    2 => '1.3',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '2.1',
    1 => '2.2',
    2 => '2.3',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '3.1',
    1 => '3.2',
  ),
)
```

I'm feeling generous today, but you should really try on you own, this was a trivial problem.

If you want to exceed `9.` then you need to find the position of the `.` using `strpos` like this

```
array_walk( $array, function($item) use (&$res){
    $key = substr($item, 0, (strpos($item,'.'))); 

    if( isset($res[$key]))
        $res[$key][] = $item;
    else
        $res[$key] = [$item];
});
```

You can test that one here ( where I changed the first item to `10.1`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a192bf28cd0fb2046e99206a2cf6ac5b2533b3c

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2);
$input_size = 3;
$newArray = array();
$newArray = array_chunk($array, $input_size);        
print_r($newArray);
```

This might be what you are looking for. You just need to convert it using array chunk and assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$a = [1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2];   

function newArray($array)
{
    $b = [];
    /* create multidimension array */
    foreach($array as $v){
        $d = (int)floor($v);
        $b[ $d ][] = $v;
    }
    /* re-index child nodes arrays to start from 1 */
    array_walk($b, function(&$item){
        $item = array_combine(range(1, count($item)), array_values($item));
    });
    return $b;
}

$b = newArray($a);

print_r($b);
```

Or even much simplier:

```
<?php

$a = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2];   

function newArray2($array)
{
    $b = [];
    $i = $j = 1;
    /* create multidimension array */
    foreach($array as $v){
        $i_ = (int)floor($v);
        if($i_ != $i){
            $j = 1;
            $i = $i_;
        }
        $b[ $i ][ $j ] = $v;
        ++$j;
    }
    return $b;
}

$b = newArray2($a);

print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by `floor()` which will return round numbers down to the nearest integer as it is seems the requirement for your desired array, try below one where you don't have to `chunk` the array as your element may vary so here is no number of element variation dependency and also with `array_chunk()` your desired array key start with 0 that is resolved with the below one :

```
<?php
    $array = array('1.1','1.2','1.3','2.1','2.2','2.3','3.1','3.2');
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        $newarray[floor($value)][] = $value;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newarray);
```

check the above working example here https://eval.in/842752

Answer (score 0):

**You should use array_chunk($array,3):**

```
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 3));

//$input_array is your array which you have defined above
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the requirement to start the numeric keys at `1` quite the programmatical irritation. This makes the code far less concise/elegant. By declaring a first element at index `0`, then un-setting it, the next key that PHP will push into will be `1` (and so on).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aN8Wt))

```
$result = [null];  // temporary declaration
unset($result[0]);  // move pointer to 1 for next push
foreach ($array as $v) {
    sscanf($v, '%d', $major);
    if (!isset($ref[$major])) {
        $result[] = &$ref[$major];
        $ref[$major] = [null];  // temporary declaration
        unset($ref[$major][0]);  // move pointer to 1 for next push
    }
    $ref[$major][] = $v;
}
var_export($result);
```

If an indexed array of indexed arrays is satisfactory, then temporary element manipulations can be omitted. Just isolate the leading integer and use it to group the reference variables that are pushed into the result array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/E9MFr))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    sscanf($v, '%d', $major);  // isolate the leading integer
    if (!isset($ref[$major])) {
        $result[] = &$ref[$major]; // push a reference to the new group into the result array
    }
    $ref[$major][] = $v; // push the current element into the current reference/group
}
var_export($result);
```